# Meaning of ジョンさんはきのう五時間しか寝ませんでした 。

Tags: meaning, past, particle-しか

So I saw this one in one my books and was wondering how it gets translated into
John slept five hours yesterday.

> ジョンさんはきのう五時間しか寝ませんでした.

Any kind of explanation is appreciated, my book maybe covers it? But I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say しか before the verb?

Comment: Oh flip, realized my spelling error... Yeah so the sentence would be: ジョンさんはきのう五時間しか寝ませんでした.

Comment: @oozeman so now you understand what the sentence is saying?  Do you want to edit the question or delete it? Still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use しか it takes the negative form of the verb. It means that a person only does that and nothing else. A more accurate translation of your sentence would be John slept for 5 hours (and did not sleep any longer)

> 水しか飲みません
>   I only drink water and nothing else
>
> チョコレートしか食べません
>   I only eat chocolate and nothing else

しか is also used with だけ

> 君だけしか守りたくない
>   I just want to protect you and nobody else